# html table con Json

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla definida en html , y lo queria rellanar con un JSON pero como soy nuevo en javascript no logre a pasar los datos correctamente
aca esta mi tabla

```
<table id="ctabco_tb" class="ctabco_tb tb_ctrl" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID </th>
                    <th title="Ordenar por.."> Nombre </th>
                    <th title="Ordenar por.."> Banco < /th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
</table>
```

aca esta mi json dentro del script

```
var datosBancos = '{"bancos":[' +'{"id":"001","nombre":"Air" ,"banco":" de la Plata"},
' +'{"id":"118","nombre":"Pepe","banco":"Salem" },'
+'{"id":"225","nombre":"Arreg" ,"banco":"Transant"},'+'
{"id":"005","nombre":"DANALD","banco":"orden"},'+
'{"id":"200","nombre":"Pablo","banco":"BNC"}]}';
```

Algun ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1):

Modifique algunas cosas en tu codigo.  Por ejemplo tu json es en realidad un string, pero si usamos el objeto json real, se podria hacer de esta forma:

```js
var datosBancos = {"bancos":[{"id":"001","nombre":"Air" ,"banco":" de la Plata"},
{"id":"118","nombre":"Pepe","banco":"Salem" },{"id":"225","nombre":"Arreg" ,"banco":"Transant"},{"id":"005","nombre":"DANALD","banco":"orden"},{"id":"200","nombre":"Pablo","banco":"BNC"}]};

var table = document.getElementById("ctabco_tb").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var i = 0;

datosBancos.bancos.forEach(function(banco) {
// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(i);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = banco.id;
cell2.innerHTML = banco.nombre;
cell3.innerHTML = banco.banco;
i++;
});
```

```html
<table id="ctabco_tb" class="ctabco_tb tb_ctrl" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID </th>
                    <th title="Ordenar por.."> Nombre </th>
                    <th title="Ordenar por.."> Banco </th>

                </tr>                
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias @alafcm , una consulta mas, en el caso que la tabla esta dentro de un div? seria igual ?

Comment: Si, es igual.  Si tu tabla tiene id, no importa en que lugar del DOM se encuentre.

Comment: Una sugerencia, veo que has hecho varias preguntas, pero no has marcado ninguna como correcta.  Es una buena practica aceptar las preguntas que te han ayudado para que la comunidad te siga ayudando.

Comment: claro estaba por hacer eso :)

Answer (score 1):

Modifique tu cadena para convertirla en un JSON.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td 
        {
            margin:10px 0;
            border:solid 1px #333;
            padding:2px 4px;
            font:15px Verdana;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>
  
  
  <script>
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {
        var bankData = [{
 "id": "001",
 "nombre": "Air",
 "banco": " de la Plata"
}, {
 "id": "118",
 "nombre": "Pepe",
 "banco": "Salem"
}, {
 "id": "225",
 "nombre": "Arreg",
 "banco": "Transant"
}, {
 "id": "005",
 "nombre": "DANALD",
 "banco": "orden"
}]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < bankData.length; i++) {
            for (var key in bankData[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < bankData.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = bankData[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
</script>
</html>
```